# Checking for other AlertDialogs in an Activity?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How do I check whether there are any `AlertDialog`s on the screen programmatically?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Aren't you starting all your dialogs yourself?  And if so, can't you just keep track of when they start/end yourself?  And how/why do you even have multiple dialogs on screen at once?

Comment: I just want to find out whether the API supports it. For instance, you can do that in swing from the parent window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, This can't be done in Android.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `myAlertDialog.isShowing();` to get a boolean of if it is showing and then do something with that information. Not exactly what you were looking for but maybe a long, convoluted work around...?

Comment: +1 This was a question that I asked long back. However as far as I remember I wanted to check if *any* AlertDialog was showing up. In that case I don't think I had any references.

Comment: Yea, I happened to be looking for a solution to my AlertDialog issue and came across this and figured I'd put that up at least. And I figured this wasn't what you had wanted but maybe it could be leveraged in a way that it could but that would be rather large chunk of coding

Comment: Hope this helps someone in the future ;) Also you can check some of my projects from my profile. They could be of help to you.